# Dump when using Drop down for create or edit opearation

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created/generated this very simple MVC program (1 minute ) ,the steps are
1. create MVC5 asp program and Create new model class - the test model
2.go to the controller add -> scaffold and provide the model and the context class.

the crud operation was generated and everything is working fine
what I want now is that wnen the user click on create in the gender he will have drop down list which he can choose,I write this code which I've from previous post and I got dump in the html drop down,what am I missing here?

the model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestropDownCreate.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string SelectedGender { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Gender
        {
            get
            {
                return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "M", Text = "Male"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "F", Text = "Female"}
            };
            }
        }
    }

        public class TestModelDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<TestModel> TestModel { get; set; }
        }



}
```

The generated view by scaffold ,you can see that I comment the generated code and put the 
@Html.DropDownListFor which cause the dump ,how should I solve it.

```
@model TestropDownCreate.Models.TestModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>TestModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedGender, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGender, Model.Gender)
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedGender)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedGender)*@
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by dump? Are you talking about a memory dump by any chance?

Comment: @Leo -  no the dump is null reference

Comment: Why are you store male and female in db like that? Best way is to use Enum for them. You also can create table for them.

Comment: @JhoonBey- can you please provide example how should I store them?

Comment: maybe this cause the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a bold suggestion based on experience that you are getting an `ArgumentNullException` exception because the value of `SelectedGender` hasn't been set. So, what's happening is that here...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGender, Model.Gender)
```

asp.net is trying to pre-select the dropdownlist with some value and to do that, it looks at the value of `SelectedGender` and attempts to match it with any of the values provided in `Gender`, however, there's nothing set for `SelectedGender` because it is null. Now, to address this issue you can follow two approaches:

1. initialize `SelectedGender` with a default value that matches one of the values specified in `Gender`...either M or F
2. Initialize `SelectedGender` with dummy default value such as an empty string, then add a default value to `Gender` as below...

   ```
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Gender
   {
       get
       {
           return new[]
       {
           new SelectListItem {Value = "", Text = "--Select a gender--"},
           new SelectListItem {Value = "M", Text = "Male"},
           new SelectListItem {Value = "F", Text = "Female"}
       };
       }
   }
   ```

A suggestion as Jhoon pointed out in a comment you don't really need to keep gender values in the database,but I understand this is out of the scope of your question

Comment: HI Leo voted up for your help.. sorry for delay in my response,for the first suggestion can you give example where should I define it,for the second suggestion I tried it and I got the same dump (I just add the first line of select gender ...did I miss something else?

Comment: Btw I you suggest to use the gender definition in other place in please let me know where?Im very new to this topic...